# I keep getting an error that i cannot figure out how to fix

Tags: c++, struct

This is for a programming assignment in one of my classes. I'm supposed to take a list of points and sort them based on the distance from a reference point. The prompt says to use a struct to store the x,y,z values of each point, and to use another struct to store the points and number of points. I get an error when i try to compile saying

```
Points.h:6:2: error: 'Point' does not name a type
Points.cpp: In function 'Points* readPoints(const char*)':
Points.cpp:25:11: error: 'struct Points' has no member named 'pointsarray'
```

What is causing this error, and how can i fix it?
There are four files concerning this, Points.h, Point.h, Points.cpp, Point.cpp.

Here's a copy and paste of Points.h:'

```
#if !defined POINTS
#define POINTS

struct Points
{
    Point** pointsarray;
    int num_points;
};
Points* readPoints(const char file_name[]);
void destroyPoints(Points* pointsarray);
void DisplayPoints(Points* pointsarray);






#endif
```

And here's a copy of Points.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
#include "Points.h"
#include "Point.h"

Points* readPoints(const char file_name[])
{
    ifstream input_file;
    input_file.open(file_name);
    int ARRAY_SIZE = 0;
    input_file >> ARRAY_SIZE;
    int i = 0;
    double x = 0;
    double y = 0;
    double z = 0;
    Points* points;
    points->num_points = ARRAY_SIZE;
    for(i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; i++){
        input_file >> x;
        input_file >> y;
        input_file >> z;
        Point* point = createPoint(x,y,z);
        points->pointsarray[i] = point;
    }
    return points;
}
```

Here's Point.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
#include "Point.h"
#include "Points.h"

#if !defined NULL
#define NULL = 0
#endif


Point* createPoint(double x, double y, double z)
{
    Point* point;
    point.x = x;
    point.y = y;
    point.z = z;
    return point;
}

void destroyPoint(Point* point)
{
    delete point;
}

void displayPoint(Point* point)
{
    cout << setprecision(3) << fixed << "(" << point->x << ", " << point->y << ", " << point->z << ")" << endl;
}
```

And here's point.h

```
#if !defined POINT
#define POINT

struct Point
{
    double x;
    double y;
    double z;
};

Point* createPoint(double x, double y, double z);
void destroyPoint(Point* point);
void displayPoint(Point* point);
#endif
```

I would greatly appreciate any solutions you can give me, thanks in advance.

Comment: Your 'Points' struct should contain 'Point's and not 'Points' - I hope it's understandable :)

Comment: This code is painful the read. Your teacher is not doing a very good job.

Comment: Why `Points* points = new Points;` and not just `Points points;`? Your code seems to go out of its way to do things the most complicated and confusing way.

Comment: The whole code is a mess. One mistake I spotted is  that points->pointsarray is not allocated. Allocating Points doesn't allocate space for member variables.

Comment: You should probably just use `vector<Point>` rather than the struct. You could do something like `typedef vector<Point> Points`

Comment: jww, my teacher likes to be a pain in the ass and overcomplicate things. he wants us to use structs, and if i use vectors, i'd probably end up losing points.

Answer (score 0):

You have:

```
struct Points
{
    Points** pointsarray;
    int num_points;
};
```

Perhaps you mean to have:

```
struct Points
{
    Point** pointsarray;
    int num_points;
};
```

Otherwise, `pointsarray` is an array of `Points*` not an array of `Point*`. That's why the compiler does not like the statement:

```
    points->pointsarray[i] = point;
```

The RHS side of that line is a `Point*`, not a `Points*`.

Comment: Changing Points to Point gives the errors: "Points.h:6:2: error: 'Point' does not name a type", "Points.cpp: In function 'Points* readPoints(const char*)':" "Points.cpp:25:11: error: 'struct Points' has no member named 'pointsarray'".

Comment: @user3530038 Can you update your post with the updated code and the error message from the compiler?

Comment: Also, `Points.h` should `#include "Point.h"`

Comment: @Matt McNabb that fixed it!